# How to prevent jquery lazy load from showing a gray background?

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I am using a jQuery [lazy load plugin found here](https://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/v1/) v1.9.3. 
The lazy loading works, but it will display a **gray background** / placeholder until the image is loaded. I also noticed an **html broken image indicator** at load start, that leads to a not so smooth loading impression.

[image]
The code I am using:

```
  $(function() {
    $("img.lazy").lazyload({
        threshold : 200,
    });
    $("img.lazy").show().lazyload();
  });
```

html:

```
<img 
 class="listImage lazy" 
 data-original="//static.example.com/image.jpg" 
 alt="title" 
 width="170" 
 height="170" 
 src="//static.example.com/image.jpg" 
 style="display: inline;"
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `placeholder`:

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload({
    threshold : 200,
    placeholder : "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAANSURBVBhXYzh8+PB/AAffA0nNPuCLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
});
```

replace with your own base64 encoded image

The broken image icon you see is because the browser essentially sees this:

```
<img src="" />
```

so you get a FOUC (Flash Of Unstyled Content) before the lazyload can replace with the placeholder.

Generally, you want to use the lazyload for images beyond the "fold" (ie not on the page initially) and normal `<img src="valid source"/>` for images that appear on the first page.

You could put the placeholder into the image tag directly, ie:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw..." data-original="realimage.jpg" />
```

Example using a base64 image placeholder:

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
```

Comment: Is there also a way to set it to a color? I also believe that something is wrong configured, as there is a broken img indicator once you hit the reload fast enough.

Comment: what do you meen by this?

Comment: Thank you. The placeholder is working now with white img 1x1, which looks good as soon as loaded. Until then it displays the entire URL (or title?) which is why it looks so bad. Did not get your comment about placeholder inline as I do add the url of the img to the src tag. Why is it not seen?

Comment: I guess the first thing that the lazyload does is replace `src=` with `src=data...` (placeholder).  If you're using `src=imgurl` then there's no need for lazyload.  If you're using `data-original=imgurl` then the image isn't loading until later to you add `src=data...` so that it loads immediately.

Comment: Great! I fixed it now. The src was actually not in the source code, but only in chrome after rendering. Put in your suggested src="... " and it works perfectly! Thank you again.